# Insert statement using variable in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am using mysql(5.7.14). I have a user table and a experiment table.

For the user table, it has columns:

```
user_id | user_name| email
```

For the experiment table, it has column:

```
user_id | experiment_id | created_at
```

I need to:

- get 10% of random user, so I have something like this:

```
SELECT user_id from user where rand() <= 0.1
```

- insert the user from the above into the experiment table, with experiment_id = 1

So I am wondering if there is a way to define a variable like:

`user_ids = SELECT user_id from user where rand() <= 0.1`

And then use it in my insert statement:

`INSERT INTO experiment VALUES (user_ids, '1', DEFAULT);`

Answer (score 2):

You could use an insert-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO experiment
SELECT      user_id, '1', DEFAULT
FROM        user
WHERE       RAND() <= 0.1
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out :D